# Modify column 2 only using awk and sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a list of 3 columns:

```
2547123456789,5391074043372870,639027123456789
```

I want to modify second column like this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\2\1/g' so that it becomes:

3519700434738207
```

My problem is how do I do  this in one line of awk/sed while leaving the other columns untouched so that my final file has:

```
2547123456789,3519700434738207,639027123456789
```

Thanks

Comment: the answer you accepted does not give the same result as you requested. It only flips the first 2 characters of the 2nd field. If this is truly what you want, please update your question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: I misread the question and thought that the `g` flag was to pick up the 2nd column.  If the OP can confirm what he wanted I'll delete my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F, '{
            printf("%s,",$1)
            len=split($2,a,"")
            for(i=1;i<len;i+=2)
              printf("%s%s",a[i+1],a[i])
            printf(",%s\n",$3)
         }' /path/to/input/file
```

#### Input

```
$ cat infile
2547123456789,5391074043372870,639027123456789
1234567890123,1234567890123456,123456789012345
```

#### Output

```
awk -F, '{printf("%s,",$1);len=split($2,a,"");for(i=1;i<len;i+=2)printf("%s%s",a[i+1],a[i]);printf(",%s\n",$3)}' ./infile
2547123456789,3519700434738207,639027123456789
1234567890123,2143658709214365,123456789012345
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed 'h;s/.*,\([^,]*\),.*/\1/;s/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g;G;s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^,]*,\)[^,]*\(.*\)/\2\1\3/' inputfile
```

Explanation:

```
# copy the line to hold space
h;
# capture the second column and retain it in pattern space
s/.*,\([^,]*\),.*/\1/;
# swap each pair of characters
s/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g;
# append the contents of hold space, now pattern space looks like
# new_field_2[newline]field_1,old_field_2,field_3
G;
# capture the fields that we want and arrange them in the proper order
s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^,]*,\)[^,]*\(.*\)/\2\1\3/
```

Comment: +1, for a moment I though it'd be impossible to do with a sed one-liner ;)