# sed search and replace specific column only

Tags: sed

Im taking weather day from wunderground.com and I and then trimming down the data for use on gnuplot. Im having trouble replacing the second column only data from number to months abbreviations. Only interested in the second column.

I want to go from this;

```
>2013 08 02 23 37 00 73.3
>2013 08 02 23 42 00 73.4
>2013 08 02 23 45 00 73.3
>2013 08 02 23 47 00 73.1
>2013 08 02 23 52 00 73.1
>2013 08 02 23 57 00 73.1
```

To this:

```
>2013 AUG 02 23 37 00 73.3
>2013 AUG 02 23 42 00 73.4
>2013 AUG 02 23 45 00 73.3
>2013 AUG 02 23 47 00 73.1
>2013 AUG 02 23 52 00 73.1
>2013 AUG 02 23 57 00 73.1
```

i am trying to use sed to change the numbers into the correct month and i keep getting this. I only want the correct sed expression to execute not all of them. This is the command i am trying to use.

```
sed -e 's/01/JAN/' -e 's/02/FEB/' -e 's/03/MAR/' -e 's/04/APR/' -e 's/05/MAY/' -e 's/06/JUN/' -e 's/07/JUL/' -e 's/08/AUG/' -e 's/09/SEP/' -e 's/10/OCT/' -e 's/11/NOV/' -e 's/12/DEC/'
```

How would i go about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050753/how-to-restrict-a-find-and-replace-to-only-one-column-within-a-csv and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525001/modify-column-2-only-using-awk-and-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",a)} {$2=a[$2+0]}1' a
>2013 Aug 02 23 37 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 42 00 73.4
>2013 Aug 02 23 45 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 47 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 52 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 57 00 73.1
```

To update the field with the new content, just redirect and then move:

```
awk .... file > temp_file && mv temp_file file
```

#### Explanation

What we do is to give `awk` a list of strings with the months names. Once we convert it into an array, `a[1]` will be Jan, `a[2]` Feb and so on. So then it is just a matter of replacing the 2nd field with `a[2nd field]`.

- `BEGIN{split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",a)}` fetches the data and inserts into the `a[]` array.
- `{$2=a[$2+0]}` sets the 2nd field as `a[2nd field]`. The `$2+0` is done to convert `08` to `8`.
- Finally `1` evaluates as true and makes `awk` perform its default action: `{print $0}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you explain the awk line in a little more detail.

Comment: you can put all in one , use `BEGIN` part to define months

Comment: @BMW is right but you don't even need the `months` variable and you don';t need the 3rd arg to split() as that's the default. All you need is `split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",a)`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton , didn't know the default of split. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nri 'G;s/$/01JAN02FEB03MAR04APR05MAY06JUN07JUL08AUG09SEP10OCT11NOV12DEC/;s/ (..)(.*)\1(...)/ \3\2/;P' file
```

This adds a lookup table to the end of each line and substitutes the key for the value.

Comment: @BMW I take no credit for this method see [here](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_tables.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Workaround that works for this problem (since your first column is very predictable) but not the general question:

```
sed -E -e 's/^([0-9]{4}) 01/\1 JAN/' -e 's/^([0-9]{4}) 02/\1 FEB/' etc.
```

`awk` has a `sub` function that could get unwieldy for many options you have here.

Perl scripts might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk's function strftime() and mktime()

```
awk '{$2=strftime("%b",mktime("2014 " $2 " 1 1 0 0"))}1' file

>2013 Aug 02 23 37 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 42 00 73.4
>2013 Aug 02 23 45 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 47 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 52 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 57 00 73.1
```

#### Explanation

- `mktime("2014 " $2 " 1 1 0 0")` fake the epoch time, use the column 2 as month
- `strftime("%b",mktime("2014 " $2 " 1 1 0 0"))` convert the epoch back to the date, with `%b`, export the abbreviated month name (Jan, Feb, etc)

#### The benefit with this awk:

It is shorter, of course. Second, you can control/adjust the format in strftime() to export any date format you like.

For example, if change to `full month name %B`. You needn't rewrite the code.

```
awk '{$2=strftime("%B",mktime("2014 " $2 " 1 1 0 0"))}1' file
```

Comment: You should state when a solution is GNU-awk specific like this one so people trying this with non-GNU awks don't waste time trying to figure out why it doesn't work for them. I try to always specifically use the command name `gawk` in those situations too just to make it very clear that it is gawk-specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{$2=substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(3*$2)-2,3)}1' file
>2013 Aug 02 23 37 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 42 00 73.4
>2013 Aug 02 23 45 00 73.3
>2013 Aug 02 23 47 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 52 00 73.1
>2013 Aug 02 23 57 00 73.1
```

Since it came up in a comment:

The idiomatic awk way to map from a month number to a name is:

```
number = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",<name>)+2)/3
```

and the above is just the natural inverse of that:

```
name = substr("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",(3*<number>)-2,3)
```

Like with anything in awk there's various ways to get the output you want but IMHO the symmetry here makes it an attractive solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{

    months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"

    name = "Jul"

    number = (match(months,name)+2)/3

    print name " -> " number

    name = substr(months,(3*number)-2,3)

    print number " -> " name

}'
Jul -> 7
7 -> Jul
```

Notice that the script uses the same definition for months no matter which direction the conversion is being done and it's a similar math calculation in both directions.

Nothing wrong with doing it this way too of course:

```
awk 'BEGIN{

    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",num2name)

    for (number in num2name) {
        name2num[num2name[number]] = number
    }

    name = "Jul"

    number = name2num[name]

    print name " -> " number

    name = num2name[number]

    print number " -> " name

}'
Jul -> 7
7 -> Jul
```

Just a few more lines of code, nbd.

Comment: Thsi is very witty! I also think it wouldn't be very changeable in case, for example, you wanted to use

Comment: It's just the natural inverse of the idiomatic awk code to map a date name to it's number: `awk 'BEGIN{print (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec","Aug")+2)/3}'` -> `8`. Symmetry is an important part of good software - google the QWAN (the Quality Without A Name).

Comment: This is very inspiring, really good stuff here. I downloaded a paper ["Foundation of the patterns"](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~kk/webstuff/Foundationofpatterns.pdf). It is closely linked to the mathematical concept of inverse functions. Of course not always you can have them, but it looks like a good way of coding. And +1 of course.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good starting point. All of this pattern stuff came out of architect Christopher Alexander travling the world trying to figure out what made some buildings (and people, etc.) "beautiful" and the answer he came up with was "symmetry". Take a photo of someone/thing generally considered beautiful, draw vertical and horizontal lines between their features (eyes, ears, etc.) and they will line up. Measurably good software has that symmetrical quality of beauty too so if you write symmetrical software it's got a better chance of being "good" than asymmetrical software.